# My tablet will not turn on. Please Help!

Tags: screen, tablet

The screen on my tablet just won't turn on, but I was told there is a fix for it. I made sure it was charged but it did nothing.

It didn't turn on when I tried to get on it, and I hadn't got on in 2 weeks.

Please Help!!!

NeuTab N7 Pro is the tablet.

Comment: "I was told there is a fix for it" Presumably you were told this by someone you described the whole problem to? There's not enough information here to help you. Please [edit] your question to describe when the problem started and what you've tried.

Comment: Is that better??

Comment: If you could unhold this so I can answer this. I found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a rip in the connection from the charging port to the battery. The solution is a new battery.